# Is a COM server a 'server'?

Tags: com

Why are COM servers called 'servers'?

Servers are usually processes running on a machine which respond to requests from clients.

COM 'servers' are just files of compiled code that can be invoked by a running process.  They should not be called servers.

Comment: At some places they call the guy who brings me food a "server". However they are not responding to requests (well - not very often anyway), they should be called "waiters"

Comment: BTW look up what `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` does

Comment: @M.M How does that deal with my point? In no way is a COM server a process that waits for a request like any other server does (eg. web server, mail server etc.)

Comment: My point is that the word "server" has more than one possible meaning

Answer (score 5):

Technically, a "server" is just a program that delivers a service. So, in COM, you have clients and servers. Of course, today we think HTTP/REST/SOA/micro service, etc. But COM existed well before that, even before an obvious concept such as "the network" (not even speaking about inter network/internet) was not so obvious.

Let's quote the official doc: [COM Clients and Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835.aspx)

> A **COM client** is whatever code or object gets a pointer to a COM server
> and uses its services by calling the methods of its interfaces.
>
> A **COM server** is any object that provides services to clients; these services
> are in the form of COM interface implementations that can be called by
> any client that is able to get a pointer to one of the interfaces on
> the server object.
>
> There are two main types of servers, **in-process** and **out-of-process**.
> In-process servers are implemented in a dynamic linked library (DLL),
> and out-of-process servers are implemented in an executable file
> (EXE). Out-of-process servers can reside either on the local computer
> or on a remote computer.
>
> In addition, COM provides a mechanism that allows an in-process server (a DLL) to run in a surrogate EXE process to gain the advantage of being able to run the process on a remote computer. For more information

It's true that many COM servers are implemented in DLL, but it's not always the case. Examples of well-known out-of-process servers: Word, Excel, etc.

Plus, as said in the last phrase, you can (almost always) turn an in-process server (so a DLL), into an out-of-process server quite easily just through configuration using surrogates. COM supplies a defaut surrogate called "dllhost.exe" that you can see sometimes in the task manager. For example, Windows Explorer uses this to protect itself from rogue in-process extensions.